# Should the Music: Practice & Theory Exchange be Split?

Tags: discussion

There are posts about learning about music, learning music, practicing music, and music theory, like this one:

[Piano technique - arms/hands/fingers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40636/piano-technique-arms-hands-fingers)

...and then questions about software:

[Does an upgrade from Ableton Live Standard to Suite cost the same if I already own Max for Live?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64901/does-an-upgrade-from-ableton-live-standard-to-suite-cost-the-same-if-i-already-o)

Should the exchange be split?

Answer (score 9):

These days, use of recording software, sampling tools, synths, effects, digital audio workstations etc is entirely part and parcel of musical practice.

Splitting these out would detract from both sites as it is the same community: **musicians**

However, asking about cost of an upgrade does seem to be off topic here.

Comment: I could see many situations where trying to split them would be very difficult. If you're trying to use software to control hardware or hardware to control software, where is the line between what is a "real" musical instrument and what is "just software"? Plus, it's not like we have such a high volume of questions here that it is hard to manage it with reasonable amounts of community participation, so there's no benefit to splitting.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Because the volume of messages is not unmanagable.  No need to split up the various methods of making music.